# SQL Date Table that lists every date for the past 60 days as well as the every 15 minute interval timestamp of each of those days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to list the past 60 days from today. I am using GETDATE and listing the past 60 days just fine, but I can not figure out how to also list the hour and minute of every day on 15 minute intervals.

For example:
2018-10-07 00:00:00,
2018-10-07 00:15:00,
2018-10-07 00:30:00
etc.

```
SELECT d AS Date,
CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,d) = CONVERT(DATE,GetDate()) Then 'Today' 
    WHEN CONVERT(DATE,d) = DATEADD(DD,-1,CONVERT(DATE,GetDate())) Then 'Yesterday'
    Else 'No' End AS 'Today'
FROM
(
  SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn -1, DATEADD(DD,-60,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())))
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DD,-61,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())),  GETDATE())) 
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2

    ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
  ) AS x
) AS y
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Same as you did with days, you just need to change it to MINUTE or HOUR just like this `DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE())` OR `DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())`

Comment: `DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DD,-61,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())),  GETDATE())` - let me guess. Something around 61?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT d = DATEADD(N, rn*-15, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) as DATETIME)) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(N, DATEADD(DD,-61,GETDATE()),GetDATE()) /15) 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.id)-1
    FROM sysobjects s1
    cross apply sysobjects s2
) AS x
```